# How to differentiate between auto-slide and click slide Bootstrap carousel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have carousel control buttons that I am adding an `active` class to when a new slide is selected.

This is a simple task when someone clicks on one of these buttons, but if I want to incorporate `autoplay`, this suddenly becomes much more challenging.

**Here is the problem:**

I can bind `slid` to a function that adds the active class to my control buttons, and it will be functional, BUT there will be a delay between the start of the slide and the addition of the active class, because `slid` is fired when the slide is complete.

Fortunately, Bootstrap provides `slide`, which is fired when a slide is initiated. I could bind `slide` to a function that adds the active class to the next slide in the list, but then this would cause problems when I try to click a control button for a slide that is out of order.

`slide` is fired whenever a slide happens, so if someone clicks on a control button that is not in the normal slide order, I will end up with two active buttons.

The only solution I can see currently, is to somehow differentiate between a `slide` event that is automatically triggered, and one that is triggered by a click.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is a great question did you ever figure it out?

Comment: This answere helped me solve this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31753085/3171256

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
  $('.carousel').carousel({
  interval: 2000
});
```

Comment: Can you provide your code or create a jsfiddle of it, so that we can help you out.

Comment: My code isn't necessary. If there's something I haven't described clearly, let me know.